# Why can you make Primitive Datatypes in C#?

Tags: c#, types

How come that in C# you can make Primitive Datatypes?

What kind of practical uses does this functionality have?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that one can make primitive data types?

Comment: Well, actually, you can't create new primitive types. There is a fixed number of primitives in C#. You can create instances of them, but that's not creating new types

Comment: I've been told once, that you can make your own datatypes. They are not the same as representing a datatype by making an Object (like Integer in Java does not entirely equals the int datatype). Is this a completely wrong understanding?

Comment: there is no such thing as 'primitive' datatypes.. all of them are objects.

Comment: I really hate when I get Minus Votes for trying to understand something. It's really...not very constructive.

Comment: @Aniket `struct`s are not objects (despite having `object` as a base-type, and being boxable); also, there are many data types in the CLI that are not managed; pointers, for example.

Comment: @Vipar if you are comparing to Java, then ask: why does `int` exist, if `Integer` does? what does `int` add? why is `int` necessary? If you have an answer to *that*, then pretty much a lot of that transfers to "why does C# have `struct`s?". Also note that in .NET, `int`===`Int32`: they are identical (just aliases for typing convenience)

Comment: @MarcGravell I believe that types such as "int" is not handled as an object internally, but handled as an integer. The Integer Representation is usually used with collections that do not accept primitive data types. Why it was made this way, I do not know.

Comment: @Vipar ah, you missed my point. What I am saying is: since `Integer` works in more places, it would seem that `int` is redundant in Java. In reality, this is not the case: if *every* usage of a *number* in Java required an *object*, the GC would go crazy.

Comment: @MarcGravell Had a feeling that would be the case, but was not really sure as it sounded too..simple to be the reason. Thank you. I'll probably accept your answer whenever I can. It really annoys me that people are so trigger happy with the Minus Giving though. I was trying to get some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean `struct`. There are various uses:

- representing simple data such as a `Point` or `ComplexValue` that doesn't warrant the overhead of an object per instance : it is just a (preferably-immutable) set of values that are a composite
- mapping fields to memory with explicit layout for interop purposes
- [avoiding GC issues](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html) for massive datasets

It is, however, ***very rare*** to declare a `struct` in C#; i.e. *vanishingly* rare. Nobody is making you do it, and if you don't like them : don't create any.

Comment: +1 for "vanishingly rare [to declare a struct]". I basically never use them and sometimes wonder whether I am missing something about them.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Think they were implemented to attract C developers and then slowly became more and more obsolete.

Comment: @Vipar no, they were implemented to solve a particular set of scenarios, which still apply just as much as they always have. The `struct` in C# (/.NET) is **very different** to the `struct` in C. If anything, I would say that the `struct` keyword was chosen purely to confuse C developers, because it behaves so very very differently.

Comment: @MarcGravell It surprises me though, since a few of the books I've tried to read on C# mention structs for "Those with C Background" as to be happy it survived in the C# world.

Comment: @Vipar I used to do a lot of book review work; a lot of books frankly get their description of `struct` *entirely incorrect*. It sounds like this book is no different. Indeed, in C++ the difference between `struct` and `class` is only: *default accessibility*. That is nothing at all like the difference between `struct` and `class` in C#.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as 'primitive' datatypes if you're coming from Java world. All of those so called primitive data types are objects in System namespace (from MSDN).

You can, however, create user defined types.. and that is the whole concept of "class" and "enums" and "structs".

See here for understanding what "primitive" data types in C# actually mean:

[primitive datatypes in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360(v=vs.80).aspx)